# Blazor landing page for not authorized users

Tags: c#, authentication, routes, blazor, blazor-webassembly

**Goal:**
I would like to have a kind of landing page if the user is not logged in (basically all other pages should be locked without the need of the `[Authorize]` attribute on all pages).

---

**Setup:**

- Blazor WASM
- ASP.NET Hosted (with IdentityServer authorization)

---

**Code:**
I have rewritten the `MainLayout.razor` to redirect all not authorized requests to my redirect handler

```
<NotAuthorized>
    <RedirectToLogin />
</NotAuthorized>
```

My `RedirectToLogin.razor` contains the landing page named `Index.razor` and the `RemoteAuthenticatorView` for auth requests

```
@inject NavigationManager Navigation
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication

@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(action))
{
    <RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@action" />
}
else
{
    <div>
        Landing page...<br />
        <a href="/authentication/Login">Login</a><br />
        <a href="/authentication/Register">register</a>
    </div>
}
```

My `RedirectToLogin.razor.cs` does listen to location changes and forwards authentication request to the `RemoteAuthenticatorView`

```
public partial class RedirectToLogin : IDisposable
{
    [CascadingParameter] private Task<AuthenticationState> AuthenticationStateTask { get; set; }

    [Inject] private NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; }

    string action = "";

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        NavigationManager.LocationChanged += LocationChanged;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        NavigationManager.LocationChanged -= LocationChanged;
    }

    async void LocationChanged(object sender, LocationChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        action = "";

        var authenticationState = await AuthenticationStateTask;

        if (authenticationState?.User?.Identity is not null)
        {
            var url = Navigation.ToBaseRelativePath(Navigation.Uri);

            if (!authenticationState.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                if (url == "authentication/logged-out")
                {
                    NavigationManager.NavigateTo("", true);
                    return;
                }

                if (url.Contains("authentication"))
                {
                    var index = url.IndexOf("authentication") + 15;
                    if (url.Contains("?"))
                        action = url.Substring(index, url.IndexOf('?') - index);
                    else
                        action = url.Substring(index);
                }
                this.StateHasChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**The Problem:**
The whole system works fine for basically all authentication requests with the **exception of login callbacks**.

**Instead of loading the authorized view it still shows the landing page.**

You need to refresh the page or click a second time on the login button to be redirected to the authorized view.

I tried to navigate the user manually on navigation change with login callback in url or when the user is authorized, but nothing seems to work.

Have you any idea why this behavior occurs and/or how this can be fixed?

---

*Please comment if there's an easier way to accomplish my goal. I didn't find anything on the net and tried my best.*

Comment: Did you change navigation from `Login.razor` after successful login? If you don't  the given `LocationChanged` callback shouldn't work as the login location is remaining same. I think, that's why you need to re-click the login button or refresh the page.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are passing everything relating to authentication to this landing page. You need to have two separate pages for what you are trying to do, one landing page for unauthorized users and one for the authorized ones.

To change this, you'll need to update your `Program.cs` file and set the `AuthenticationPaths` under `builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization`. Here's an example:

```cs
builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AuthenticationPaths.LogInPath = "auth/login";
    options.AuthenticationPaths.LogInCallbackPath = "auth/login-callback";
    options.AuthenticationPaths.LogInFailedPath = "auth/login-failed";
    options.AuthenticationPaths.LogOutPath = "auth/logout";
    options.AuthenticationPaths.LogOutCallbackPath = "auth/logout-callback";
    options.AuthenticationPaths.LogOutFailedPath = "auth/logout-failed";
    options.AuthenticationPaths.LogOutSucceededPath = "auth/logged-out";
    options.AuthenticationPaths.ProfilePath = "auth/profile";
    options.AuthenticationPaths.RegisterPath = "auth/register";
    options.AuthenticationPaths.RemoteProfilePath = "/profile";
    options.AuthenticationPaths.RemoteRegisterPath = "/register";
});
```

Then the `Authentication.razor` page:

```html
@page "/auth/{action}"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action">
    <LoggingIn></LoggingIn>
    <CompletingLoggingIn></CompletingLoggingIn>
    <LogInFailed>Failed to log in.</LogInFailed>
    <LogOut></LogOut>
    <LogOutFailed>Failed to log out.</LogOutFailed>
    <CompletingLogOut></CompletingLogOut>
    <LogOutSucceeded><RedirectToLogin ReturnUrl="Dashboard"/></LogOutSucceeded>
    <UserProfile></UserProfile>
    <Registering></Registering>
</RemoteAuthenticatorView>

@code{
    [Parameter] public string Action { get; set; }
}
```

For more info on the `RemoteAuthenticatorView`, check out this Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-5.0#customize-app-routes

and just below that section: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-5.0#customize-the-authentication-user-interface