# Login link not working in Blazor WASM using Auth0

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, auth0

My Blazor WASM uses Auth0 authentication and I created a separate layout page that I use for public pages that are for unauthenticated users. Basically, I followed Steve Sanderson's approach and created a `CustomRouteView`. Here's his response to a question that is identical to what I want to do: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/26122#issuecomment-698855892

And here's the `CustomRouteView.razor` code:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering

<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <LayoutView Layout="typeof(MainLayout)" ChildContent="(RenderFragment)RenderPageWithParameters" />
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <LayoutView Layout="typeof(PublicLayout)">
           <Public />
        </LayoutView>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>

@code {

    [Parameter] public RouteData RouteData { get; set; }

    private void RenderPageWithParameters(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.OpenComponent(0, RouteData.PageType);
        foreach (var kvp in RouteData.RouteValues)
        {
            builder.AddAttribute(1, kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        }
        builder.CloseComponent();
    }
}
```

And here's `App.razor` code:

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <CustomRouteView RouteData="@routeData" />
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

I also followed the official documentation by Auth0 to implement authentication/authorization in my app. Here's that document: https://auth0.com/blog/securing-blazor-webassembly-apps/

Everything is pretty much working except one thing which is the login link. So, if the user is not logged in, the app uses the `PublicLayout.razor` which looks like this:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div>
   @Body
</div>
```

My `Public.razor` component looks like this:

```
@inject NavigationManager Navigation

<div>
   <p>Please login</p>
   <p><Button @onclick="LoginClicked">Click to Login</Button>
</div>

@code {

   private void LoginClicked()
   {
      Navigation.NavigateTo("/authentication/login");
   }

}
```

When I click the button, I see the URL change in the address bar to `https://localhost:12345/authentication/login` but nothing happens. I placed a break point in the `@code{}` section of `Authenticaation.razor` and I noticed that I'm NOT hitting it so this component is NOT loading.

What am I doing wrong here?

BTW, I'm also open to suggestions for alternative approaches to using a separate layout page for public pages that are for unauthenticated users.

P.S. Before I created the separate layout for public pages, the login link was working fine. So when I followed the Auth0 documentation, everything worked fine. The login link stopped working after I started using the `PublicLayout.razor` but there's not much in there anyway.

Comment: "Nothing happens" means that no request is sent to the server? Or the request is made but nothing happens on the server side?

Comment: No request is sent to the server. As mentioned in my post, I see the URL in the address bar change but it doesn't invoke the Auth0 login process.

Comment: I don't know the details of the layout switching approach, but as far as I understand it looks like the component mapped to `https://localhost:12345/authentication/login`, i.e., the `Client/Pages/Authentication.razor` component is not loaded.
That makes me think of a problem on the layout switching mechanism, honestly

Comment: The `Authentication.razor` is definitely NOT loading. I put a break point at the beginning of `@code{}` section and I'm not hitting it. I also found this post that suggests the authentication paths must be registered in `Program.cs`. I tried that to no avail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66522039/blazor-landing-page-for-not-authorized-users

Comment: I don't think it's related to authentication. Blazor doesn't even know what `Authentication.razor` is going to do. It could be any Razor page component.

Comment: @AndreaChiarelli I agree. Something to do with the custom route view. Interestingly, it seems simple enough though.

Comment: The approach suggested by @BrianParker in this question actually works fine. Here's his answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77467929/1705266