# AuthorizeView in MainLayout in Blazor WASM

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm using Auth0 authentication in my Blazor WASM app and trying to NOT display the top header and nav bar for unauthenticated users so I added `AuthorizeView` to both my `MainLayout.razor` and `Home.razor` in order to display the correct content.

Here's my `MainLayout.razor`:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <div class="page">

            <Header />

            <NavMenu />

            <main id="main" class="main">
                @Body
            </main>

        </div>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <main>
            @Body
        </main>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

And here's my `Home.razor`:

```
@page "/"

<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
       <div class="pagetitle">
       ... // Omitted for brevity
       </div>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <Public />
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

The `<Public />` component provides the link necessary to initiate the authentication process.

And here's the `App.razor`:

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" />
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

It's "almost" working right except for one thing: when authenticated, I don't see the `<Header />` and `<NavMenu />` but I do see the page content for home page. When unauthenticated, it all works fine. It's only when authenticated, the layout isn't rendering the way I intend it to.

Any idea why the header and nav are being ignored? Do I need anything else in either my `MainLayout.razor` or `Home.razor` to make this simple omission of header/nav to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encapsulate `AuthorizeRouteView` with `AuthorizeView` Use a different layout for each state.

```html
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <AuthorizeView Context="AppAuthState">
            <Authorized>
                <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" 
                                    DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                    <NotAuthorized>
                        ...
                    </NotAuthorized>
                </AuthorizeRouteView>
            </Authorized>
            <NotAuthorized>
                <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData"
                                    DefaultLayout="@typeof(PlainLayout)">
                    <NotAuthorized>
                        ...
                    </NotAuthorized>
                </AuthorizeRouteView>
            </NotAuthorized>
        </AuthorizeView>
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(PlainLayout)">
            <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

Comment: This is working nicely. Thank you. Though I'm still unclear why in my original approach the page content would display correctly but not the header and nav menu. Why the selective rendering? BTW, this actually answers another question I'd posted. I originally wanted to use different layouts but couldn't get it to work. This answers that but like I said, I'd still like to understand why the approach I show in the question renders the page content but not the header/nav bar.